# Lists/'Unexpected EOF while parsing'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not sure why my coding doesn't work, it's supposed to return a list of only even numbers specifically in brackets (like a list). The error message just says 'Unexpected EOF while parsing' and I have no idea what that means. Thanks for the assistance!

```
def chooseEven(nums):
    newList = list()
    for num in nums:
        if num%2==0:
            newList.append(num)
        return newList

chooseEven([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Can you post the traceback please?

Comment: Your indentation is off - `return newList` should line up with the `for`, not be within it.  Not that that's the cause of your problem, which I can't reproduce with the code you've provided.

Comment: you probably have a string literal somewhere else in your code that you didn't close.